# VSCode highlights

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a reason that when I import my local functions into vscode, some of them are highlighted properly (and allow you to CTRL + LMB to direct you to them) but some of them aren't? This applies to all themes not just the one I'm using. Also, all the the imports are functionable - nothing is broken.

Reference image:

[image: Reference Image]

I've looked into each of the "white" functions (can't show photos due to company privacy), and nothing is different in the way they import things and implement methods - not sure why this is happening and is really triggering my OCD.

Comment: It seems like your editor doesn't think those are modules to import. How is the project structured?

Comment: It might be a path issue. Where is `helper_modules` stored (with respect to the source file that does the import, and with respect to the project directory)? In case the module is part of a virtual environment, is VSCode configured to use that environment? In case the module is stored somewhere else (probably using some `sys.path` tricks) the IDE will likely fail to find all files/objects which causes the symbols to remain white. If you can't share your project due to company policy, please try to create a [mre] that you can share.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Also add the version number of your Python extension installation.

Comment: some else posted a similar question recently: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76782471/11107541

Comment: please add the code in the screenshot as text to your question post so others can reproduce the issue (see the definition of a [mre]). Please also tell us what you see in the language mode indicator at the bottom right of the screen.

Comment: Try opening other Python files in VS Code to see if they are highlighted correctly. If so, the problem may be a Syntax error or other problem in your file. If not, then the problem may be with your VS Code or Python extension, try to reinstall the extension and reload vscode.