# Python code is not color coded and no code suggestions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently got VS Code for Python and I am trying to write code but it doesn't suggest code when I write it *and* the text is not color coded. I tried changing my color theme from Dark to Dark+ and it still doesn't work. The only extension I have is the Python extension in VS Code.

Comment: juanapa.arrivillaga yes my file is named hello.py

Comment: I would try uninstalling and reinstalling the python extension, then restart VS code, and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @MyCodeMadeMeSuicidal I tried that and it did not work

Comment: when you are editing a python file, does it say "python" on the bottom right? can you post a screenshot of editing a python file?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the python works when i run it on the terminal its just the coloring of the code that annoys me

Comment: @AaryanKigni that isn't what I asked. I understand you aren't getting syntax highlting, I was asking about your editor, i.e. VSCode, and trying to ascertain whether it is properly recognizing the language.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well in that case no, when I edit my file it doesn't say python at the bottom right in VS code. I have also noticed this, in VS code, when others create their file by using .py, it shows a python logo when they create it, in my case it shows the windows logo.

Comment: can you please post a screen shot... what type of file is being recognized? You should be able to click and set it.

Comment: Also, which Python extension do you have installed? Is it the official one from Microsoft?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76776587/11107541

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Also add the version number of your Python extension installation.

Answer (score 0):

Read [document about python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense).

According to your problem,

Firstly, you can check whether you installed [the python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and you have to ensure that you have chosen the correct python interpreter by shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type **Python: Select Interpreter**.

Then, you can add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

If IntelliSense still isn't working, try restarting VS Code.

Comment: the default value of that setting is `"Default"`, which means "Automatically select a language server: Pylance if installed and available, otherwise fallback to Jedi.". The Pylance extension is part of the Python extension pack.