# My IDE(vs code) has stopped recognizing some files

Tags: python, go, visual-studio-code

When I create a `.py` or `.go` file, My IDE does not recognize this files, even as I have python extensions and Golang extensions. I have both python and Golang installed on my Ubuntu already.

I have tried updating my VS code, still same problem. I also updated my python3 and Golang to the latest version, yet nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not recognize"?

Comment: How, exactly, are you creating the files?  Are you creating them in vs code?  editing a file with notepad?  downloading them from the web?

Comment: what does the language mode indicator at the bottom right show for python and go files?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.

Comment: potentially related also very recent questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76782471/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/76776587/11107541

Answer (score 0):

Try running the built-in troubleshooter. It's meant for scenarios like this one.

---

1. Make sure you have the newest version of VS Code
2. Click <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (or <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> on mac) + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
3. Type in troubleshoot

[image: visual studio code command window example]

4. Click on `Help: Troubleshoot Issue`, and follow it's instructions

Answer (score 0):

##### Reinstall after [uninstalling vscode completely](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that u have installed extension for it (especially `LSP - language server provider`). If u use vim/neovim, then sometimes you need to create "project folder" which is identified by git dotfile folder -> this is created by `git init`.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to to see the lsp-config for the language server and try install it for vscode
all lsp configs is there ::

https://github.com/neovim/nvimlspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md